# "Top n% overall" label appears to be blank

Tags: bug, profile-page, reputation-leagues

The ["top n% overall" label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCJIG.png) appears to be blank for [this user](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/29119/elyar-abad).

> [image]

Code:

```
<span class="js-rank-badge grid--cell s-badge s-badge__votes fs-fine bc-blue-3 fc-blue-700"><!-- unranked --></span>
```

Not sure why that happens.

Comment: [Rob](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users/282094/rob) found what is related to that: [*The problem is that they are not present in the Reputation Leagues database*](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8152060#8152060)

Answer (score 5):

You're only ranked in the reputation league database once you get more than 200 rep on a site and that only happened today for this user on Politics.

Wait 24 hours for the nightly job that calculates ranks and the rank should appear.